# AJAX: JSON.parse cant get value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have code like this

```
$.post('data.check.php', {NKI: v_NKI}, function(cek_NKI) {
    var cek_NKI=JSON.parse(cek_NKI);

    $.post('data.check.php', {id: id_ang}, function(cek_NKI_update) {
        var cek_NKI_update=JSON.parse(cek_NKI_update);  <-- why this code not running and var cek_NKI_update still not fill up ?? :(
        if(cek_NKI_update.NKI_before == v_NKI){
            blablabla;
        }
    });

    if(cek_NKI.NKI_exist){
        window.alert('NKI is exist!');
    } else {
        blablabla;
    }

});
```

and for **data.check.php**

```
if ($_POST['id'])
{
    $id_ang = $_POST['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tb_anggota WHERE id_ang='$id_ang'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $NKI = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['NKI']);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tb_ang WHERE NKI='$NKI'");

    $NKI_exist = mysql_num_rows($query); //records count
    echo json_encode(array('NKI_exist'=> $NKI_exist, 'NKI_before'=> $data['NKI']));
}
```

my problem is there is something make my code stuck dan some line code not running.. but I dont know why because my editor not showing warning and I think my logic is not wrong..

maybe somebody know?? thanks

Comment: Try removing the `JSON.parse` line

Comment: Where is it not running? `console.log` is your friend. You also should be looking at your browser, not your editor for errors.

Comment: @Musa can you explain more clearly? thanks

Comment: Check the request result in your Browser Dev Tools' Network tab.

Comment: in your second post `$_POST['NKI']` seems `undefined` your post is only: `{id: id_ang}` maybe you need to add `NKI: v_NKI`...

Comment: @epascarello my log: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Comment: Sounds like you do not have a string with JSON in it. `console.log(cek_NKI)`

Comment: @epascarello `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: AND what is being returned from the server?

Comment: @epascarello `Uncaught ReferenceError: cek_NKI is not defined`

Comment: Um, did you not include that inside your callback? `function(cek_NKI) { console.log(cek_NKI);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform the first post:

`$.post('data.check.php', {NKI: v_NKI}, function(cek_NKI){`

and you sand: `NKI` like POST data.

`if($_POST['id'])` is false and your PHP return a JSON string (I dont't know how), and after you perform the second request:

`$.post('data.check.php', {id: id_ang}, function(cek_NKI_update) {`

but here you sand only `id` (like POST data) but in your php code you try to get:

`$_POST['NKI']`

but you haven't send inside the second `$.post`, it seems `null`.

Try to change your secondo post call to:

`$.post('data.check.php', {id: id_ang,NKI: v_NKI}, function(cek_NKI_update) {`